# How to pass a stream responseType to my client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, axios

I am trying to download a file from my express js app :

```
const response = await Axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    responseType: 'stream'
  })
```

However rather than doing this right after :

`response.data.pipe(Fs.createWriteStream(path))`

I want to send the response to my js client that requested my express js app with ajax, so that the file will directly be downloaded from my browser (client side) instead of server-side.

Any solution ?

Comment: take a look at the server sent events this may suffice your requirement [----->SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the express response object to the pipe method

```
response.data.pipe(res);
```

Comment: In my client in get a result as a VERY long string e.g. `UEsDBAoAAAANNKSeeUUAAAAAAAAAAAAAYYYAJABAAc3ltcGhvbnkvVVgMAAjQdFQU0HRU9Q...` . I've tried to do `new Blob([result]) etc.` but then I get a corrupted file. Any suggestion ?
`

Comment: Looks like base64 encoded data(for a zip file)